# Counting the message length of a thread in Facebook

Tags: facebook-fql

I'm reading the message_count parameter in Facebook's "Thread" table using this query:
        SELECT message_count, thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0 AND viewer_id=me()

Results I get are many times wrong, for example I get a count of ~800 for a thread with 24 comments.
Any idea why? is this a bug?
Is there any other way to get the length of a conversation without counting the number of comments in the thread itself?

Comment: Do you get the same result when getting the info from the Graph API instead? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/thread/

Comment: How do I do that? If I give the graph api the thread_id I can see all the comments and count them, but the  message_count parameter is not displayed. I'm trying to avoid running on every message thread in orer to count the comments

Comment: thread does not have a comments connection – so I’m guessing you’re not really looking at a thread object. Go to `/me/threads/ first to get the thread id.

Comment: I'm using thread to count messages not comments. I think I do have the correct thread id as I get it from the thread table.

Comment: My question was about the messge_count field from the thread table that gives me the wrong information.

Answer (score 0):

The message count field is correct and I've tested it on a few threads, the API probably isn't pulling all the response back for you in the

`SELECT message_id, body FROM message WHERE thread_id = THREAD_ID` call

You can fiddle with this using LIMIT and OFFSET parameters.